# Pass value from form to URL

Tags: forms

I just want a simple form that sends the user to an adress with a added value from the form. Like http://example.com(value from input name "epost")

Is it possible to do that without any script etc?

```
<form method="get" action="http://google.com">
E-post:<br>
<input type="text" name="epost"> 
<p>
Organisation
<select name="organisation">
<option value="1">org 1</option>
<option value="2">org 2 Korset</option>
</p>
</br>
 <input type="submit" value="Done">
</form>
```

Comment: You cannot update the form's action without any script

Answer (score 0):

You can send params in url using GET:

```html
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" target='_blank'>
  Key word:
  <input type='text' name='q' value='Rob' />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=Rob" target='_blank'>Search for Rob</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is pretty much what I was looking for. I just need to understand how the script-thing is working. I tried to search for an answer but couldn't find any.